# How to add field for logsstream from specific name in elasticserach logstream

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I simply need to add my logfile parameter on log stream header, is that possible on elastic search?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. click settings on the top left
2. + add column

If it's not available as field, you can use [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok.html) to parse the data and create a brand new field.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for replaying its log4j logs and its not in the setting area have check other alternative options

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. If you are familiar with Logstash or any other data pipeline processor it can be easier for you to generate a new field during indexing. Otherwise the grok I mentioned in reply will be the best solution.

Please let me know the result.

Comment: grok {
        match => { "message" => "trace_id=%{DATA:trace_id}" }
    }

Hii , i added the above in Logstash, after that how that id visualize in kibana

Comment: Hey, looks like there is a typo. There is no `trace_id` but `trace-id` in your data. The field must be populated to use in logsstream. Once the new field created you can add column like the above. Debug your grok before run the logstash and don't forget to check logstash logs. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-grokdebugger.html